# Searching and Sorting on same field name in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, full-text-search, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and trying to use it over a data where a person can search on some text (say entity.name) and the apply sort on the result list.

Below is my mapping :

```
    {
      "entity": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          { "text_custom_field_template": {
            "match":              "ltd_text_*",
            "mapping": {
              "type":           "text"
            }
          }}
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "treeId": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
          "entity.name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "fields": {
              "sort": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
          "entity.url": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "entity.details": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    id       name            details     is_marked
    13    ABC entity        details        1
    14    BCD  entity        details        1
    15    DEF  entity        details        1
    16    EFG  entity        details        1
    17    GHI                details        1
    18    Untitled entity    details        1
```

I want to search for all entity with name having entity and then sort the result alphabetically.
        If I run below on elastic search I am getting same result for asc and desc :

```
    {
       "query":{
          "multi_match":{
             "query":"entity",
             "fields":[
                "entity.details^1.0",
                "entity.name^4.0",
             ],
             "type":"best_fields",
             "operator":"AND",
             "slop":0,
             "prefix_length":0,
             "max_expansions":50,
             "lenient":false,
             "zero_terms_query":"NONE",
             "boost":1.0
          }
      },
        "sort":{
        "entity.name.sort" : "asc"
       }
    }

    Result :
    BCD
    EFG
    GHI
    Untitled
    ABC
```

Also is there a way to support the same(search and sort) for new custom field of text type which can be added by a client ?